# Sibling package imports

Tags: python, package, python-import, siblings

I've tried reading through questions about sibling imports and even the
[package documentation](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references), but I've yet to find an answer.

With the following structure:

```
├── LICENSE.md
├── README.md
├── api
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── api.py
│   └── api_key.py
├── examples
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── example_one.py
│   └── example_two.py
└── tests
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── test_one.py
```

How can the scripts in the  `examples` and `tests` directories import from the
`api` module and be run from the commandline?

Also, I'd like to avoid the ugly `sys.path.insert` hack for every file. Surely
this can be done in Python, right?

Comment: I recommend skipping past all the `sys.path` hacks and reading [the only actual *solution*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50193944/1222951) that's been posted thus far (after 7 years!).

Comment: By the way, there's still room for another good solution: Separating executable code from library code; most of the time a script inside a package shouldn't *be* executable to begin with.

Comment: This is so helpful, both the question and the answers. I am just curious, how come "Accepted Answer" is not the same as the one awarded the bounty in this case?

Comment: @Aran-Fey That's an underrated reminder in these relative import error Q&As. I've been looking for a hack this whole time, but deep down I knew there was a simple way to design my way out of the problem. Not to say that it's the solution for everyone here reading, but it's a good reminder as it could be for many.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

### Seven years after

Since I wrote the answer below, modifying `sys.path` is still a quick-and-dirty trick that works well for private scripts, but there has been several improvements

- [Installing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50193944/760767) the package (in a virtualenv or not) will give you what you want, though I would suggest using pip to do it rather than using setuptools directly (and using `setup.cfg` to store the metadata)
- [Using the `-m` flag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23542795/760767) and running as a package works too (but will turn out a bit awkward if you want to convert your working directory into an installable package).
- For the tests, specifically, [pytest](https://pytest.org) is able to find the api package in this situation and takes care of the `sys.path` hacks for you

So it really depends on what you want to do. In your case, though, since it seems that your goal is to make a proper package at some point, installing through `pip -e` is probably your best bet, even if it is not perfect yet.

### Old answer

As already stated elsewhere, the awful truth is that you have to do ugly hacks to allow imports from siblings modules or parents package from a `__main__` module. The issue is detailed in [PEP 366](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0366/). [PEP 3122](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3122/) attempted to handle imports in a more rational way but Guido has rejected it one the account of

> The only use case seems to be running scripts that happen
>   to be living inside a module's directory, which I've always seen as an
>   antipattern.

([here](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-3000/2007-April/006793.html))

Though, I use this pattern on a regular basis with

```
# Ugly hack to allow absolute import from the root folder
# whatever its name is. Please forgive the heresy.
if __name__ == "__main__" and __package__ is None:
    from sys import path
    from os.path import dirname as dir

    path.append(dir(path[0]))
    __package__ = "examples"

import api
```

Here `path[0]` is your running script's parent folder and `dir(path[0])` your top level folder.

I have still not been able to use relative imports with this, though, but it does allow absolute imports from the top level (in your example `api`'s parent folder).

Comment: you don't *have to* if you [run from a project directory using `-m` form or if you install the package](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23542795/4279) (pip and virtualenv make it easy)

Comment: How does pytest find the api package for you? Amusingly, I found this thread because I'm running into this problem specifically with pytest and sibling package importing.

Comment: I have two questions, please. 1. Your pattern seems to work without `__package__ = "examples"` for me. Why do you use it? 2. In what situation is `__name__ == "__main__"` but `__package__` is not `None`?

Comment: @actual_panda Setting `__packages__` helps if you want absolute path such as `examples.api` to work iirc (but it has been a long time since I last did that) and checking that package is not None was mostly a failsafe for weird situations and futureproofing.

Comment: Gosh, if only other languages would make the same process as easy as it is in Python. I see why everyone loves this language. Btw, documentation is also excellent. I love extracting return types from unstructured text, it's a nice change from Javadoc and phpdoc. ffs....

Comment: @JuniorIncanter two years late, but [here's the documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/goodpractices.html#choosing-a-test-layout-import-rules)

Comment: @Evpok Would you mind elaborating on how to install it without setuptools?

Answer (score 424):

## Tired of sys.path hacks?

There are plenty of `sys.path.append` -hacks available, but I found an alternative way of solving the problem in hand.

#### Summary

- Wrap the code into one folder (e.g. `packaged_stuff`)
- Create `pyproject.toml` file to describe your package (see minimal `pyproject.toml` below)
- Pip install the package in editable state with `pip install -e <myproject_folder>`
- Import using `from packaged_stuff.modulename import function_name`

---

## Setup

The starting point is the file structure you have provided, wrapped in a folder called `myproject`.

```
.
└── myproject
    ├── api
    │   ├── api_key.py
    │   ├── api.py
    │   └── __init__.py
    ├── examples
    │   ├── example_one.py
    │   ├── example_two.py
    │   └── __init__.py
    ├── LICENCE.md
    ├── README.md
    └── tests
        ├── __init__.py
        └── test_one.py
```

I will call the `.` the root folder, and in my example case it is located at `C:\tmp\test_imports\`.

### api.py

As a test case, let's use the following ./api/api.py

```
def function_from_api():
    return 'I am the return value from api.api!'
```

### test_one.py

```
from api.api import function_from_api

def test_function():
    print(function_from_api())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_function()
```

### Try to run test_one:

```
PS C:\tmp\test_imports> python .\myproject\tests\test_one.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\myproject\tests\test_one.py", line 1, in <module>
    from api.api import function_from_api
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'api'
```

### Also trying relative imports wont work:

Using `from ..api.api import function_from_api` would result into

```
PS C:\tmp\test_imports> python .\myproject\tests\test_one.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\tests\test_one.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ..api.api import function_from_api
ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

---

## Steps

###### 1) Make a pyproject.toml file to the root level directory

(previously people used a setup.py file)

The contents for a minimal `pyproject.toml` would be*

```
[project]
name = "myproject"
version = "0.1.0"
description = "My small project"

[build-system]
build-backend = "flit_core.buildapi"
requires = ["flit_core >=3.2,<4"]
```

---

###### 2) Use a virtual environment

*If you are familiar with virtual environments, activate one, and skip to the next step.* Usage of virtual environments are not *absolutely* required, but they will *really* help you out in the long run (when you have more than 1 project ongoing..). The most basic steps are (run in the root folder)

- Create virtual env

  - `python -m venv venv`
- Activate virtual env

  - `source ./venv/bin/activate` (Linux, macOS) or `./venv/Scripts/activate` (Win)

To learn more about this, just Google out "python virtual env tutorial" or similar. You probably never need any other commands than creating, activating and deactivating.

Once you have made and activated a virtual environment, your console should give the name of the virtual environment in parenthesis

```
PS C:\tmp\test_imports> python -m venv venv
PS C:\tmp\test_imports> .\venv\Scripts\activate
(venv) PS C:\tmp\test_imports>
```

and your folder tree should look like this**

```
.
├── myproject
│   ├── api
│   │   ├── api_key.py
│   │   ├── api.py
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── examples
│   │   ├── example_one.py
│   │   ├── example_two.py
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── LICENCE.md
│   ├── README.md
│   └── tests
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── test_one.py
├── pyproject.toml
└── venv
    ├── Include
    ├── Lib
    ├── pyvenv.cfg
    └── Scripts [87 entries exceeds filelimit, not opening dir]
```

---

###### 3) pip install your project in editable state

Install your top level package `myproject` using `pip`. The trick is to use the `-e` flag when doing the install. This way it is installed in an editable state, and all the edits made to the .py files will be automatically included in the installed package. *Using pyproject.toml and -e flag requires pip >= 21.3*

In the root directory, run

`pip install -e .` (note the dot, it stands for "current directory")

You can also see that it is installed by using `pip freeze`

```
Obtaining file:///home/user/projects/myproject
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Checking if build backend supports build_editable ... done
  Getting requirements to build editable ... done
  Preparing editable metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: myproj
  Building editable for myproj (pyproject.toml) ... done
  Created wheel for myproj: filename=myproj-0.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl size=903 sha256=f19858b080d4e770c2a172b9a73afcad5f33f4c43c86e8eb9bdacbe50a627064
  Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-qohzx1u0/wheels/55/5f/e4/507fdeb40cdef333e3e0a8c50c740a430b8ce84cbe17ae5875
Successfully built myproject
Installing collected packages: myproject
Successfully installed myproject-0.1.0
(venv) PS C:\tmp\test_imports> pip freeze
myproject==0.1.0
```

---

###### 4) Add `myproject.` into your imports

Note that you will have to add `myproject.` only into imports that would not work otherwise. Imports that worked without the `pyproject.toml` & `pip install` will work still work fine. See an example below.

---

## Test the solution

Now, let's test the solution using `api.py` defined above, and `test_one.py` defined below.

### test_one.py

```
from myproject.api.api import function_from_api

def test_function():
    print(function_from_api())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_function()
```

### running the test

```
(venv) PS C:\tmp\test_imports> python .\myproject\tests\test_one.py
I am the return value from api.api!
```

---

* here using flit as build backend. Other alternatives exist.

** In reality, you could put your virtual environment anywhere on your hard disk.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed post. Here is my problem. If I do everything you said and I do a pip freeze, I get a line `-e git+https://username@bitbucket.org/folder/myproject.git@f65466656XXXXX#egg=myproject` Any Idea on how to resolve?

Comment: Why doesn't the relative import solution work? I believe you, but I'm trying to understand Python's convoluted system.

Comment: I have not digged into this so deeply to understand *why* it does not work; I just see that relative imports beyond top-level package are not allowed. I have also noticed that making pip-installable packages out of my python packages/apps have made my python experience better. But that's of course very subjective :)

Comment: Good answer but it's unclear why `setup.py` is required?

Comment: You need the `setup.py` to make your python code a pip-installable python package.

Comment: Has anyone has problems with regards to a `ModuleNotFoundError`? I've installed 'myproject' into a virtualenv following these steps, and when I enter an interpreted session and run `import myproject` I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myproject'`? 

`pip list installed | grep myproject` shows that it is there, the directory is correct, and both the verison of `pip` and `python` are verified to be correct.

Comment: To fix the problem, at least for me, make sure the directory containing all the code has the same name as what you've called it in `setup.py` - for me, this was my `src` directory.

Comment: It works but it prints following(4 times) while importing from sibling directory to console. `None
{'name': 'MyProject', 'path': None}
` . Same class when imported from current directory doesn't print anything

Comment: Soo.. How does this works? I finally made it work, but I do not fully understand, I can import my Package, but if I do `pip freeze` It is not on list

Comment: @GrzegorzKrug: Is the `pip` command pointing to the right `pip` executable? Does `python -m pip freeze`  give the same results?

Comment: Hey @np8, it works, I accidentally installed it in venv and in os :) `pip list` shows packages, while `pip freeze` shows weird names if installed with flag **-e**

Comment: @np8 Hey, I have encountered similar issue and I have made sure I did everything as you said in the post. Could you have a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58896546/7784797)?

Comment: Spent about 2 hours trying to figure out how to make relative imports work, and this answer was the one that finally actually did something sensible. 

Comment: @ThoseKind I also encured same problem, `pip freeze` have the same output with you. After caerfully read this anwser, I found my directory structure is wrong. Please note that `.` at this anwser's directory structure, the setup.py is at the same level with `myproject`, not inside the `myproject` folder, I put setup.py in the `myproject` by mistake, after move setup.py out, everything works.

Comment: What I think is sickening is that I have to come to stackoverflow to find a real answer on how to do relative imports correctly. The documentation around this stuff really needs to be improved.

Comment: [PEP 517](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0517/) does not support editable installs as noted on [setuptools](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html?highlight=517#setup-cfg-only-projects) . What is the safest, most flexible way of adding directories to python lookup path? I'd like to avoid sys.path and pythonpath hacks, and so far this is the best answer.

Comment: @DanielTuzes I think this is a question which is broad enough to be posted as a standalone question on SO

Comment: What specifically is responsible in adding the root package to the path in this procedure? For me it's working on one machine but not the other. Python can be so much fun....

Comment: In my case the suggested methods works well. but my question is how this code will be deployed. is it through the python pip package ? which can be installed only through pip install ? I need more clarification if anyone can help here.

Comment: Do you have to do pip installs every time your code / directory structure changes, ethough?

Comment: @Joe Flack if using the -e flag you only install once and changes to code are reflected automatically.

Comment: I am getting `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'api'`  even though `findpackages()` returns `['myproject.api', ...]`

Comment: @scrollout you need to `import myproject.api` or `from myproject import api`.

Comment: @sinoroc the issue was my module was called `helpers`. To test this, I renamed it to `helpers2` and it worked.

Comment: I had same issue as @ThoseKind and kept getting error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myproject'`. I fixed the issue by creating a virtual environment using `virtualenv` instead of using `venv`. I don't understand why I get different results based on the method used to create the virtual environment. Note: I use VS Code to test my code.

Answer (score 51):

Here is another alternative that I insert at top of the Python files in `tests` folder:

```
# Path hack.
import sys, os
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('..'))
```

Comment: +1 really simple and it worked perfectly. You need to add the parent class to the import (ex api.api, examples.example_two) but I prefer it that way.

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning to newbies (like myself) that `..` here is relative to the directory you're executing from---not the directory containing that test/example file. I'm executing from the project directory, and I needed `./` instead. Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: @JoshDetwiler, yes absoluely. I was not aware of that. Thanks.

Comment: This is a poor answer. Hacking the path is not good practice; it's scandalous how much it's used in the python world. One of the main points of this question was to see how imports could be done while avoiding this kind of hack.

Comment: `sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..'))`
@JoshuaDetwiler

Comment: @teuber789 I don't see anything wrong with using this approach in dev to allow developers to quickly test things out and decide to move code around etc.
This approach is absolutely acceptable for early-stage projects or bigger rewrites as a mechanism.

Answer (score 46):

You don't need and shouldn't hack `sys.path` unless it is necessary and in this case it is not. Use:

```
import api.api_key # in tests, examples
```

Run from the project directory: `python -m tests.test_one`.

You should probably move `tests` (if they are api's unittests) inside `api` and run `python -m api.test` to run all tests (assuming there is `__main__.py`) or `python -m api.test.test_one` to run `test_one` instead.

You could also remove `__init__.py` from `examples` (it is not a Python package) and run the examples in a virtualenv where `api` is installed e.g., `pip install -e .` in a virtualenv would install inplace `api` package if you have proper `setup.py`.

Comment: @Alex the answer does not assume that tests are API tests *except* for the paragraph where it says  explicitly *"if they are api's unittests"*.

Comment: unfortunately then you are stuck with running from root dir and PyCharm still does not find the file for its nice functions

Comment: @mhstnsc: it is not correct. You should be able to run `python -m api.test.test_one` from anywhere when the virtualenv is activated. If you can't configure PyCharm to run your tests, try to ask a new Stack Overflow question (if you can't find an existing question on this topic).

Comment: @jfs I missed the virtual env path but i don't want to use anything more than shebang line to run this stuff from any directory ever. Its not about running with PyCharm. Devs with PyCharm would know also they have completion and jump through functions which i could not make it work with any solution.

Comment: @mhstnsc an appropriate shebang is enough in many cases (point it to the virtualenv python binary. Any decent  Python IDE should support a virtualenv.

Answer (score 13):

### For readers in 2023: If you're not confident with `pip install -e` :

TL;DR: A script(usually an entry point) can only `import` anything the same or below its level.

Consider this hierarchy, as recommended by an answer from [Relative imports in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69102148/5290519):

```
MyProject
├── src
│   ├── bot
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── main.py
│   │   └── sib1.py
│   └── mod
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── module1.py
└── main.py
```

To run our program from the starting point with the simple command `python main.py`, we use **absolute import** (no leading dot(s)) in `main.py` here:

```py
from src.bot import main


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main.magic_tricks()
```

The content of `bot/main.py`, which takes advantage of **explicit relative imports** to show what we're importing, looks like this:

```
from .sib1 import my_drink                # Both are explicit-relative-imports.
from ..mod.module1 import relative_magic

def magic_tricks():
    # Using sub-magic
    relative_magic(in=["newbie", "pain"], advice="cheer_up")
    
    my_drink()
    # Do your work
    ...
```

These are the reasonings:

- We don't want to give "OK, so this is a module" a funk when we want to run our Python program, sincerely.

  - So we use *absolute import* for the entry point `main.py`, this way we can run our program by simply `python main.py`.
  - Behind the scene, Python will use `sys.path` to resolve packages for us, but this also means that the package we want to import can **probably be superseded by any other package of the same name** due to the ordering of paths in `sys.path` e.g. try `import test`.
- To avoid those conflicts, we use *explicit relative import*.

  - The `from ..mod` syntax makes it very clear about "we're importing our own local package".
  - But the drawback is that you need to think about "OK, so this is a module" again when you want to run the module as a script.
- Finally, the `from ..mod`  part means that it will **go up one level to `MyProject/src`**.

#### Conclusion

1. Put your `main.py` script **next to** the root of all your packages `MyProject/src`, and use absolute import in `python main.py` to import anything. No one will create a package named `src`.
2. Those explicit relative imports will just work.
3. To run a module, use `python -m ...`.

#### Appendix: More about running any file under `src/` as a script?

Then you should use the syntax `python -m`  and take a look at my other post: [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sib1'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69095357/5290519)

Comment: This actually worked for me. I think without this "src" directory/package, the subpackages didn't have common root package.

Answer (score 12):

I don't yet have the comprehension of Pythonology necessary to see the intended way of sharing code amongst unrelated projects without a sibling/relative import hack.  Until that day, this is my solution.  For `examples` or `tests` to import stuff from `..\api`, it would look like:

```
import sys.path
import os.path
# Import from sibling directory ..\api
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + "/..")
import api.api
import api.api_key
```

Comment: This would still give you the api parent directory and you wouldn't need the "/.." concatenation  sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))

Answer (score 6):

For siblings package imports, you can use either the *insert* or the *append* method of the *[sys.path][2]* module:

```
if __name__ == '__main__' and if __package__ is None:
    import sys
    from os import path
    sys.path.append( path.dirname( path.dirname( path.abspath(__file__) ) ) )
    import api
```

This will work if you are launching your scripts as follows:

```
python examples/example_one.py
python tests/test_one.py
```

On the other hand, you can also use the relative import:

```
if __name__ == '__main__' and if __package__ is not None:
    import ..api.api
```

In this case you will have to launch your script with the ['-m' argument](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m) (note that, in this case, you must not give the *'.py'* extension):

```
python -m packageName.examples.example_one
python -m packageName.tests.test_one
```

Of course, you can mix the two approaches, so that your script will work no matter how it is called:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    if __package__ is None:
        import sys
        from os import path
        sys.path.append( path.dirname( path.dirname( path.abspath(__file__) ) ) )
        import api
    else:
        import ..api.api
```

Comment: I was using the Click framework which doesn't have the `__file__` global so I had to use the following: `sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0]))))`
But it works in any directory now

Comment: There are no good answers to this. And shows how the makers of python must live in some fantasy bubble where a relative import is just almost impossible.

Answer (score 2):

You need to look to see how the import statements are written in the related code.  If `examples/example_one.py` uses the following import statement:

```
import api.api
```

...then it expects the root directory of the project to be in the system path.

The easiest way to support this without any hacks (as you put it) would be to run the examples from the top level directory, like this:

```
PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:. python examples/example_one.py
```

Comment: With Python 2.7.1 I get the following: `$  python examples/example.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "examples/example.py", line 3, in <module>
    from api.api import API
ImportError: No module named api.api`. I also get the same with `import api.api`.

Comment: Updated my answer...you **do** have to add the current directory to the import path, no way around that.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone using Pydev on Eclipse end up here: you can add the sibling's parent path (and thus the calling module's parent) as an external library folder using *Project->Properties* and setting *External Libraries* under the left menu *Pydev-PYTHONPATH*. Then you can import from your sibling, e. g. `from sibling import some_class`.

Answer (score 1):

I made a sample project to demonstrate how I handled this, which is indeed another sys.path hack as indicated above. [Python Sibling Import Example](https://github.com/ADataGMan/python-sibling-import-example), which relies on:

`if __name__ == '__main__': import os import sys sys.path.append(os.getcwd())`

This seems to be pretty effective so long as your working directory remains at the root of the Python project.

Comment: This only works if you are running from the script's parent directory

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to comment on the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323860/sibling-package-imports/50193944#50193944) provided by np8 but I don't have enough reputation so I'll just mention that you can create a setup.py file exactly as they suggested, and then do `pipenv install --dev -e .` from the project root directory to turn it into an editable dependency. Then your absolute imports will work e.g. `from api.api import foo` and you don't have to mess around with system-wide installations.

[Documentation](https://pipenv-fork.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basics.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using pytest then the [pytest docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/goodpractices.html#test-discovery) describe a method of how to reference source packages from a separate test package.

The suggested project directory structure is:

```
setup.py
src/
    mypkg/
        __init__.py
        app.py
        view.py
tests/
    __init__.py
    foo/
        __init__.py
        test_view.py
    bar/
        __init__.py
        test_view.py
```

Contents of the `setup.py` file:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(name="PACKAGENAME", packages=find_packages())
```

Install the packages in **editable** mode:

```
pip install -e .
```

The pytest article references [this blog post by Ionel Cristian Mărieș](https://blog.ionelmc.ro/2014/05/25/python-packaging/#the-structure).

Answer (score -1):

Check the "site-packages" folder for the Python installation, and add or update 'easy_install.pth', so that it includes the path to the directory of the script that should be imported.

Entries in such `.pth` files make the named folders work the same way as the `site-packages` folder (i.e., they are added to `sys.path` at startup).

Answer (score -2):

**in your main file add this:**

```py
import sys
import os 
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(__file__,mainScriptDepth)))
```

mainScriptDepth = the depth of the main file from the root of the project.

Here is your case  `mainScriptDepth = "../../"`. Then you can import by specifying the path (`from api.api import *` ) from the root of your project.

Answer (score -2):

## Don't want to edit sys.path by hand and dislike editable installs?

`pip install importmonkey`

[[github](https://github.com/hirsimaki-markus/importmonkey)]

[[pip](https://pypi.org/project/importmonkey/)]

### Example structure:

You want to import something from parent / sibling path but it fails with one of these: `ModuleNotFoundError` or `ImportError` or `SystemError`

```
├─ src
│   └─ project
│       ├─ __init__.py
│       └─ module.py
└─ test
    └─ test.py
```

### The solution:

```py
# In test.py
# You can add as many paths as needed, absolute or relative, in any file.
# Relative paths start from the current __file__ directory.
# Normal unix path conventions work so you can use '..' and '.' and so on.
# The paths you try to add are checked for validity etc. help(add_path) for details.

from importmonkey import add_path
add_path("../src")
import project
```

Disclosure of affiliation: I made importmonkey.

Comment: I can also just do `import sys; from pathlib import Path; sys.path.insert(0, str((Path(__file__).parent / '..' / 'src').resolve()))` (or the `os.path` variant thereof) without the need to install and import a third party package. So how is using your package any better? Note that with _pytest_ I can just do it once and tuck it away inside `conftest.py` and the other test files like `test_foo.py`, `test_bar.py`, ... just pick it up automatically, as _pytest_ applies `conftest.py` to all of them.

Answer (score -4):

First, you should avoid having files with the same name as the module itself. It may break other imports.

When you import a file, first the interpreter checks the current directory and then searchs global directories.

Inside `examples` or `tests` you can call:

```
from ..api import api
```

Comment: I get the following with Python 2.7.1: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example_one.py", line 3, in <module>
    from ..api import api
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package`

Comment: Oh, then you should add a `__init__.py` file to the top level directory. Otherwise Python can't treat it as a module

Comment: It won't work. The issue is not that the parent folder is not a package, it is that since the module's `__name__` is `__main__` instead of `package.module`, Python can't see its parent package, so `.` points to nothing.

Answer (score -5):

1. **Project**

1.1 **User**

1.1.1 *about.py*

1.1.2 ***init**.py*

1.2 **Tech**

1.2.1 *info.py*

1.1.2 ***init**.py*

Now, if you want to access *about.py* *module* in the **User package**, from the *info.py* *module* in **Tech package** then you have to bring the cmd (in windows) path to Project i.e.
**C:\Users\Personal\Desktop\Project>**as per the above Package example. And from this path you have to enter, **python -m Package_name.module_name**
For example for the above Package we have to do,

**C:\Users\Personal\Desktop\Project>python -m Tech.info**

*Imp Points*

1. Don't use .py extension after *info module* i.e. python -m Tech.info.py
2. Enter this, where the siblings packages are in the same level.
3. -m is the flag, to check about it you can type from the cmd *python --help*