# How do I import a Python script from a sibling directory?

Tags: python, import, path, pythonpath

Let's say I have the following directory structure:

```
parent_dir/
    foo_dir/
        foo.py
    bar_dir/
        bar.py
```

If I wanted to import `bar.py` from within `foo.py`, how would I do that?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323860/sibling-package-imports/27878845#27878845

Answer (score 58):

If all occurring directories are Python *packages*, i.e. they all contain `__init__.py`, then you can use

```
from ..bar_dir import bar
```

If the directories aren't Python packages, you can do this by messing around with `sys.path`, but you shouldn't.

Comment: this will not work if you want to import in a non package and you just run a python from a sibling. In this case sys.path.append is the way to go

Comment: @mhstnsc I'd say in this case you have done something wrong, but if it's just some hacky script it might be OK to mess around with `sys.path`.

Comment: Its not wrong but when running the main module you cannot do relative imports. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0366/

Comment: When I run `ipython foo.py` on this, I get `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`. I've added an `__init__.py` file to the parent directory and the `bar_dir` directory

Comment: @ogogmad, did you find a solution to this? Thanks

Comment: Just like @ogogmad, running it with `python3` also gives the same error. `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`

Comment: This does work in Python 3.8, but requires that the parent package is accessible to Python, and that the module is imported as part of that package. I should probably expand this answer a little, but don't have time to do so.

Answer (score 47):

You can use the `sys` and `os` modules for generalized imports. In `foo.py` start with the lines

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('../bar_dir'))
import bar
```

Comment: Note that this will use the sibling directory of the cwd, not the sibling directory of where `foo.py` is.  To use the script's directory, use `sys.path.append(os.path.normpath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), '..', 'bar')))`

Comment: The only thing that worked on this entire page.

Answer (score 4):

Let's say if you have following structure:

```
root
  |_ productconst.py
  |_ products
     |_ __init__.py
```

And if you would like to import productconst in `products.__init__`, then following can be used :

```py
from ..productconst import *
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're having issues in python 3+, the following worked for me using `sys.path.append("..")`.

```
sys.path.append("..")
from bar_dir import bar
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the proposed answers have relied on altering `sys.path`. IMHO - this is not neccessary if you can retain the relative folder structure correctly.  I was inspired by the response of a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54361477/how-to-import-python-modules-from-sibling-directory):

Please see my worked out example below. I have followed the same folder structure as in your question

### Folder structure

[image]

After expanding the folder **parent_dir**

[image]

### bar_dir/bar.py

The file `bar.py` implements a skeletal class `Bar`

```py
class Bar():
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pass

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return "This is an instance of Bar"
    
    def some_method(self) ->None:
        pass
```

### bar_dir/**init**.py

```py
from .bar import Bar
```

### foo_dir/foo.py

The file `foo.py` implements a simple class `Foo` which in turn references the class `Bar` through a constructor parameter.

```py
from ..bar_dir import Bar

class Foo():
    def __init__(self ,bar_instance: Bar) -> None:        
        self._bar=bar_instance

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"You are inside an instance of Foo and you have just accessed bar={self._bar}"
```

### foo_dir/**init**.py

```py
from .foo import Foo
```

---

### sfo_main.py

This is main runner script which glues together `foo_dir` and `bar_dir` packages

```py
import parent_dir.bar_dir as bar_lib
import parent_dir.foo_dir as foo_lib


if __name__ == "__main__":
    f=foo_lib.Foo(bar_instance=bar_lib.Bar())
    print(f"This is an instance of foo={f}")
    print(f"{bar_lib.Bar()}")
```

### Output from sfo_main.py

[image]

### Why use a **init**.py ?

https://docs.python.org/3.9/tutorial/modules.html

### Documentation on relative imports

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html