# Importing modules from a sibling directory for use with py.test

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, importerror, pytest

I am having problems importing anything into my testing files that I intend to run with py.test.

I have a project structure as follows:

```
/ProjectName
|
|-- /Title
|    |-- file1.py
|    |-- file2.py
|    |-- file3.py
|    |-- __init__.py
|
|-- /test
|    |-- test_file1.py
```

I have not been able to get any import statements working with pytest inside the `test_file1.py` file, and so am currently just attempting to use a variable declared in `file_1.py` and print it out when `test_file1.py` is run.

file1.py contains:

```
file1_variable = "Hello"
```

test_file1.py contains:

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('../Title'))
import file1

def test_something():
    assert file1.file1_variable == "Hello"

print(file1.file1_variable)
```

The import statement from my testing file is taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/10272919/5477580 which works by editing the PYTHONPATH variable.  This allows me to run the `test_file1.py` script and successfully execute the `print` statement.

However, attempting to run `py.test` from the `/ProjectName` directory gives me an error saying `ImportError: No module named 'file1'`

Is there some way in which I can structure things better so that pytest will be possible? Do I need to add something to my `__init__.py` file?

Comment: The reason the `sys.path` hack didn't work is because `os.path.abspath('../Title')` gives the wrong path, in turn because the path is relative to the current working directory of the process, **not** the source file where you call it. This problem is not actually anything to do with the import system. Please see the linked duplicate for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't need to add anything to `__init__.py`. This file tells Python to treat the parent directory as a module that can be imported as [described here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages).
Just add it to your Title directory and import it like

```
from ..Title.file import file1_variable
```

here we are moving 1 hierarchy above in the directory just like `cd ..`

Note `..` is for reaching the Title package from **test** directory. If you need to run your file from **ProjectName** directory, you will have to do

```
from Title.file import file1_variable
```

Comment: That's working, thank you very much. I think I was just misinterpreting the structure of hierarchical import statements.  However, it seems that my pytest will run into errors again if there are import statements in file1.py.  For example, say file1.py imports some function from file2.py, running pytest will then say there is no module named file2.py.  Do I have to explicitly declare each of these in the test file?

Comment: This is simply wrong. First off, a relative import like this can only work as long as `ProjectName` is a package - which it normally shouldn't be, because the same folder would contain all the non-Python stuff used for setting up a distribution. Second, `__init__.py` doesn't tell Python any such thing - **in Python 3.2 and before** it says to treat the folder as a **package**, but in 3.3 onward (3.3 came out almost 4 years before this answer was posted) it is not necessary for this purpose. Third, OP's goal is to do an absolute import instead, which makes more sense for test code.