# ImportError shows up with py.test, but not when running the app

Tags: python, python-3.x, importerror, pytest, circular-dependency

Unlike in this question:
[Importing modules from a sibling directory for use with py.test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37469473/importing-modules-from-a-sibling-directory-for-use-with-py-test)
I can import something from my app, but there's an import error (looking like a circular dependency) that raises from *'inside'* `myapp` while running the test and not when running `myapp` alone:

```
$ python3 myapp/myapp.py
Some dummy string (correct output)
```

But:

```
$ python3 -m pytest                                                                               
================================================================= test session starts =================================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.4.3, pytest-2.9.1, py-1.4.31, pluggy-0.3.1
rootdir: /home/nico/temp/projects_structures/test04/myapp, inifile: 
plugins: cov-2.2.1
collected 0 items / 1 errors 

======================================================================= ERRORS ========================================================================
________________________________________________________ ERROR collecting tests/test_things.py ________________________________________________________
tests/test_things.py:4: in <module>
    from myapp.lib.core.base import do_things
myapp/lib/core/base.py:1: in <module>
    from lib import something
E   ImportError: No module named 'lib'
=============================================================== 1 error in 0.05 seconds ===============================================================
```

As you can see, the problem is *not* the `import` statement from the test file. It's raised from 'inside' `myapp`.

Here is the complete structure:

```
.
└── myapp
    ├── myapp
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── lib
    │   │   ├── core
    │   │   │   ├── base.py
    │   │   │   └── __init__.py
    │   │   └── __init__.py
    │   └── myapp.py
    └── tests
        └── test_things.py
```

myapp.py contains:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from lib.core import base

base.do_things()
```

lib/__init__.py contains:

```
something = "Some dummy string (correct output)"
```

base.py contains:

```
from lib import something

def do_things():
    print(something)
    return True
```

and test_things contains:

```
import unittest
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '..')
from myapp.lib.core.base import do_things

class DoThingsTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_do_things(self):
        self.assertTrue(do_things())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

And `$PYTHONPATH` seems correctly set (so this: 
[Py.test No module named *](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20985157/py-test-no-module-named)
doesn't answer my problem). (Or if this is not correct, how can I correct it?)

```
$ echo $PYTHONPATH
/home/nico/temp/projects_structures/test04/myapp/myapp
```

Comment: I can't answer what the problem here is exactly, but messing with `sys.path` and `PYTHONPATH` is always a recipe for trouble. I'd recommend just installing your project in a [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/) or using [tox](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and using fully qualified imports like `from myapp.lib import something`.

Comment: @TheCompiler thanks for these hints. I didn't precise it because it was already a long post, but usually `PYTHONPATH` is empty (problem remains exactly the same). I don't like to mess with `sys.path` neither, but I have seen somewhere there's no other choices for using `py.text` with python3. So I will check if virtualenv and/or tox do help to solve the case (though I would expect them not to be necessary for that).

Comment: Where did you read that? I'm (and I'm sure countless others are) using pytest just fine with python3 without any `sys.path` shenanigans.

Comment: Can you try this and let me know the output ? `$ export PYTHONPATH=<ABSOLUTE PATH TO TOPMOST myapp dir> ` and  from myapp root `py.test tests/test_things.py`

Comment: @Sanju same output, unfortunately. I've tried setting to `/home/nico/temp/projects_structures/test04/myapp/myapp` and to `/home/nico/temp/projects_structures/test04/myapp`. The script works when it runs alone, but the test fails with the very same message. It looks like there's a kind of "shift" between tests and myapp. If I put `from myapp.lib import something` in `base.py`, I get the contrary: myapp does not work (ImportError), but the tests finish sucessfully!

Comment: @Sanju, OK, I should have mistyped something, as I retried `$ export PYTHONPATH=/home/nico/temp/projects_structures/test04/myapp/myapp` and it seems to have solved the case now. You could add this as an answer.

Comment: @TheCompiler I'm 100% sure I've seen that in SO (because I haven't figured out this on my own); I have been struggling to find it again, in vain, I give up.

Comment: glad it helped , will add that an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting the PYTHONPATH should do the trick.

```
$ export PYTHONPATH=<ABSOLUTE PATH TO TOPMOST myapp dir>
```

(in this example, it is the path to myapp/myapp; and ensure you've *exported* `PYTHONPATH`, not only set it).

and from myapp run either

```
$ py.test
```

or

```
$ python3 -m pytest
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way of doing this is to put a `conftest.py` file into the top level of `myapp`, or in `myapp/tests`. Like this:

```
$ pwd
/home/nico/temp/projects_structures/test04/myapp/tests
$ touch conftest.py
$ cd ..
$ py.test
================================================================= test session starts =================================================================
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.6, pytest-2.9.1, py-1.4.31, pluggy-0.3.1
rootdir: /home/nico/temp/projects_structures/test04/myapp, inifile: 
collected 1 items 

tests/test_things.py .

============================================================== 1 passed in 0.05 seconds ===============================================================
$
```

(and `PYTHONPATH` is empty:

```
$ echo $PYTHONPATH

$
```

)

This way, `py.test` automatically adds `myapp` to `PYTHONPATH`. This avoids to forget exporting `PYTHONPATH` and will make the tests of `myapp` easier for other devs (who neither will need to solve this problem).