# How to import a module from a sibling directory that imports modules in its directory in Python 3.9 without modifying sys.path?

Tags: python, python-import, importerror, modulenotfounderror

My project file structure looks something like this:

```
hyphenated-project-root/
    __init__.py
    src/
        __init__.py
        module0.py
            > from module1 import MyClass
            > import module2
        module1.py
            > class MyClass: ...
        module2.py
            > from module1 import MyClass
    scripts/
        __init__.py
        script1.py
            > import module2
```

The `__init__.py` files are empty and both `module0.py` and `script1.py` have `__name__ == "__main__":` blocks. Those two files are supposed to serve as entry points to the system.

However, I get various forms of import error when I try `python src/module0.py arg1 arg2` or `python scripts/script1.py` (or `python -m scripts.script1`) from my terminal in the project root. I've tried several variations of `import module2`, modifying the `__init__.py` files, nesting `scripts/` under `src/` and messing with `import_module` from [`importlib`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/importlib.html), but nothing seems to resolve the issue.

Is it possible to make this work without modifying `sys.path`? In particular, can it also be done without using the packaging system (e.g. building a package with `setuptools` and installing it)?

None of these were able to answer the question for me:

- [python import from sibling folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48690887/)
- [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/)
- [What does from __future__ import absolute_import actually do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33743880/)
- [Importing files from different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/)
- [How to import python modules from sibling directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54361477/)
- [Sibling package imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323860/)
- [import module from a sibling directory in python3.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70395407/)

Comment: This question really deserves an answer. It's unbelievable how complicated this is in Python, and most of the answers provided elsewhere don't work for Python 3.9.