# Need to know clean way to have import work when program is run from different directories

Tags: python, import

Assuming I have this 3 directory structure.

- Dir_A

  - Dir_B

    - b.py
  - Dir_C

    - c.py

So Dir_B and Dir_C are subdirectories of Dir_A and they each contain 1 .py file.   b.py needs to import c.py and I want to
be able to run b.py while I"m in either the Dir_B directory or the
Dir_A directory.   What is the cleanest/simplest way to do the
import of b.py?  I know I can modify the sys.path but not sure how to do it and the import cleanly and portably so it works in both of these cases.

Comment: If I use the accepted answer in the above link then I get this error:
"ValueError:  Attempted relative import in non-package".  By the way, I do have empty __init__.py files in all 3 directories.

Comment: and if i use this answer:
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('../Dir_C'))
import c
then it works when I execute "python b.py" from Dir_B but the import does not work when I execute "python Dir_B/b.py" from Dir_A.  The import fails in that case because it is relative to Dir B not Dir_A.   So what I"m asking is how to make it work for both of these cases not one or the other.

Comment: the answers I'm referring to are the ones at this link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10272879/how-do-i-import-a-python-script-from-a-sibling-directory

Comment: Please reopen this.  I have explained why neither of the answers in the link referenced in the closure do not solve this.  I don't know what else to do to explain.