# Unable to call function from another python file (in another directory)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

On ubuntu, I am working with the following structure:

```
.
├── src
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── main.py
└── test
    ├── __init__.py
    └── test.py
```

The `main.py` contains the following function:

```py
def fun(x,y):
    return x+y
```

And the test.py has

```py
from src.main import fun
print(fun(2,3))
```

I am working in the directory `daddy`. So `pwd` prints `daddy`.

When I try calling `test.py`,

```
$ python3 test/test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from src.main import fun
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
```

### What options do I have, to get this right ?

---

**I have gone through other answers related to this and they don't work for me... chiefly because they don't deal with working directory unlike my case.**

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10272879/how-do-i-import-a-python-script-from-a-sibling-directory)

Comment: Typically the folder where the modules that you run is situated will be added to the `PYTHONPATH`. So, it is a good idea to have a properly structured project and a test runner that discovers tests. Which testing framework do you use?

Comment: I am using `unittest` and I use `python -W ignore -m unittest discover -v` to automatically detect all the tests but this is a project small enough to ignore writing all the tests. I am trying to discover alternatives that dont requires writing tests everytime.