# Python Import for unittests driving me nuts

Tags: python, python-module, python-unittest

I know that there are other questions like this, none of them worked for me.  I've been creating a simple python app and decided to organize it (instead of having the app and test.py in the same directory.  I tried to set it up like this:

C:\Dev\project\module\test

```
- project
    - __init__.py
    - module
        - __init__.py
        - module.py
        - test
             - __init__.py 
             - test_module.py
```

Now I've tried everything i can think of to import module.py to test_module.py

```
import module
import project.module
import module.module
import project.module.module
from project import module
from project.module import module
```

None of these work.  It fails with:

```
ImportError: No module named 'whatever i put in above'
```

It's driving me nuts, shouldn't this be simple?  What am i missing?  I added a test that shows my PYTHONPATH using import sys print sys.path.  The first item in the list is C:\Dev\project\module\test

**EDIT:**

I tried adding init to the top level as well and that didn't help.  I know I could force edit the sys.path as many of the answers suggest.

What is the *right* way to do it? As in, what is the standard or sensible way to build a project to avoid this issue?

Comment: Could you add a `__init__.py` to `project`? This means Python will read that directory as a Python module.

Comment: Have you tried adding the path containing your unit test to PYTHONPATH?

Comment: Here are some good recommendations regarding project structure: http://blog.habnab.it/blog/2013/07/21/python-packages-and-you/

Comment: I also recommend using a `virtualenv` and `setuptools` so you can install, use and develop your package at once after running `python setup.py develop`

Comment: rename both `__int__.py` to `__init__.py`

Answer (score 0):

Messing with the python path programmatically isn't usually considered great style, but it has its uses. I find it's a nice, quick way to do what you're doing (writing tests below/inside a module). Of course the easy way is to simply put your tests outside of the module. Barring that, however, just do this:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, r'C:\Dev\project') # Add the directory containing your module.
import module
```

This way, you ensure that the first directory on the path is the directory that contains the module you want to import. You could also avoid hard-coding the module path (e.g. if you want to be able to move your project someplace else) by using a path that's relative to your testing script:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(__file__, '..', '..', '..')))
import module
```

This will work no matter where you run the script from, and cross-platform.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to reach the parent directory, you can use:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '..')

import module
```

This should work on both Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 0):

At I beginning of most of my python scripts, I always put the following:

```
# Path hack.
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323860/sibling-package-imports
import os, sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('.'))
```

I think packaging is a bit screwed in python, yet this is a standard way for me to make it work :)

When executing my script, I always use the root directory as the working dir:

```
cd C:\Dev\project
python3 .\module\test\test_module.py
```

When importing submodules, I also always start the path from the root:

```
import module.module
```

or

```
from module.module import some_identifier
```