# Absolute or Relative Imports in Python (3.4) with Sibling Directories

Tags: python, package

My package is far more complex, but here's everything stripped out and made easier to read as an example:

```
sound/                         
      __init__.py               
      formats/                 
              __init__.py
              wavread.py
              wavwrite.py
      effects/                  
              __init__.py
              echo.py
```

(Note: I borrowed this structure from [the official tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/modules.html))

I want to be able to reference *echo.py* from *wavwrite.py*.

In *wavwrite.py*, I made my reference this way:

```
from ..effects import echo
```

And I get this error:

```
File "C:\sound\formats\wavwrite.py", line 1, in <module>
   from ..effects import echo
SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import
```

I had a friend comment that I should try an absolute import, and in that case, I get a different issue.

In *wavwrite.py*, I made my reference this way:

```
from effects import echo
```

Or

```
import effects.echo as echo
```

And I get this error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'effects'
```

This all looks correct to me based upon how I understand this should work, and it's driving me nuts. It has to be something simple that I'm missing.

Comment: Just try "from effects import echo " it might work as effects package and wavwrite are in same package "formats"

Comment: @TanveerAlam, I've actually tried "from effects import echo" and "import effects.echo as echo", both yield the results "ImportError: No module named 'effects'"

Comment: Import should be like 'from .effects import echo'

Answer (score 1):

So I found an answer [elsewhere on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323860/sibling-package-imports#answer-6466139), but I don't like it:

```
from sys import path
from os.path import dirname as dir
path.append(dir(path[0]))

from effects import echo
```

This functions, but it looks very ugly, and it seems like it should be unnecessary. Can anyone improve upon this?