# Python create package for local use

Tags: python, package

I have three big project that are independant:

- Communication protocol
- Interface User
- User environment

The communication protocol will be included in the interface user, and the interface user will be used in the user environment.

We are at work, so I cannot upload anything on internet.

I wanted to do package for each big project. And install thoses packages in the other project. But I cannot find a way to do it locally, without having to upload to Pypi or the equivalent for testing.

How can I create package-style project and include them to my other projects without using internet ?

Answer (score 1):

[Documentation is your friend.](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) You don't need to register your script on pypi, you can just run the setup script and install  locally.

Answer (score 0):

I had a setup similar to your situation, and [this solved it for me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50193944/1145339) - creating a local regular package of your big project, which then allowed the sub-folders to see each other when importing.