# Python making import statements independent from exact location

Tags: python, import

What's the best way in `Python` to make code independent from where it is located?

In a project of mine I have a lot of code (in different files) which all need to access the same objects defined and created somewhere else.

In a perfect world:

**somewhere.py**

```
from registry import register
...
register(Cat(), "cat")
...
```

**somewhere_else.py**

```
from magic import cat
...
cat.pet()
...
```

However this would most likely involve overriding the import system, so I'm also happy with any implementation that sort of mimics this system, ex. `magic.get('cat')` instead of `from magic import cat`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried relative imports? Maybe something like `from ..registry import register` ? The dots allow to access the parent directory.

Comment: Do `somewhere.py`, `somewhere_else.py`, `registry` and `magic` all belong to the same project? Files in the same project should use relative imports like `from .registry import register`. Projects with dependencies on other projects should require all dependencies to be *installed* and thus importable from anywhere.

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50193944/1222951).

Comment: (They all belong to the same project),It's more when one of the files is moved, rather than relative imports. (for example when the project file structure is changed)

Comment: If you change the project structure then of course you must update the code to reflect it. Any decent IDE should be able to do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

Structuring your project into sub-packages and importing things in `__init__.py` could solve your problem (if I understand it correctly). For example:

If your project is structured like:

```
root
├── animals
│   ├── cat.py
│   ├── dog.py
│   └── __init__.py
└── main.py
```

you can have:

**cat.py:**

```
class Cat:
    pass
```

**dog.py:**

```
class Dog:
    pass
```

**__init__.py**

```
from .cat import Cat
from .dog import Dog
```

**main.py**

```
from animals import Dog, Cat  # we don't specify exact modules, just a sub-package name
# do stuff with these animals
```