# How to import a class into a python file from an outside directory?

Tags: python

I'm fairly new to python and currently struggling to do the simple thing of importing a file from an outside directory.

Let's consider two files :

```
// src/class/Rider ....

class Rider(object) :
    def __init__(self, firstname, lastname, emailaddress, phonenumber, pickuplocation, dropofflocation, pickuptime, dropofftime):
        self.FirstName = firstname
        self.LastName = lastname
        self.EmailAddress = emailaddress
        self.PhoneNumber = phonenumber
        self.PickUpLocation = pickuplocation
        self.DropOffLocation = dropofflocation
        self.PickUpTime = pickuptime
        self.DropOffTime = dropofftime

    def set_rider_name(self):
        first = self.FirstName
        last = self.LastName
        return first + last
```

and

```
//src/method/rider

# importing Rider class in here ...
```

I'm struggling to import the `Rider` class from `src/class/Rider` into the `src/method/rider` file so I can actually use that class.

Coming from node.js and being used to the `import/export` of `es6` , I'm still learning `python 2.7`.

my root directory is something like : `../Golf-cart/src` , where I have `class` and `method` subdirectories inside `src/`

How can I import my class definition into my method file so I can actually use it there ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sibling package imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323860/sibling-package-imports)

Comment: This topic didn't really solved my problem since it not working ...

Comment: Don't edit answers into the questions, as they invalidate the answers below. Instead, add an answer below, and mark it as accepted if it solves your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the **empty file** `__init__.py` in both directories `/src/class/__init__.py` and `/src/method/__init__.py`.

Then you just import like

```
#/src/method/rider.py

import class.Rider
...
```

That's it. Hope it help.

Comment: so where should I put `import class.Rider` ? in `/src/method/` ? That where I need the class to be called.

Comment: Yes, `/src/method/rider.py` as your mention.

Comment: and what should I put int `__init__` ?

Comment: Nothing, just create the blank file.

Comment: Great to hear that.!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use `sys` to add the directory to the system path, then you can import the file directly.

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'system/path/to/Rider')
import Rider
```

Comment: I still have `no module to Rider ...`

Comment: how did you type the system path to insert?