# attempted relative import beyond top-level package whilst trying to run unit test

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

This is the folder structure of my python project:

```
src->
    stock_alerter->
                 tests
```

Inside the folders stock_alerter and tests I have an empty `__init__.py`

Inside stock_alerter I have a file stock.py containing:

```
class Stock:
    def __init__(self, symbol):
        self.symbol = symbol
        self.price = None
```

Inside tests I have a file test_stock.py containing:

```
import unittest
from ..stock import Stock

class StockTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_price_of_a_new_stock_class_should_be_None(self):
        stock = Stock("GOOG")
        self.assertIsNone(stock.price)
```

When I run test_stock.py I get:

```
ValueError('attempted relative import beyond top-level package')
```

I did some searches but changing

```
from ..stock import Stock
```

to:

```
stock import Stock
```

gives:

```
ModuleNotFoundError("No module named 'stock'")
```

Any ideas? Btw, I use Visual Studio Express 2017 and ran test_stock.py.

PS:

Adding:

```
import os,sys,inspect
currentdir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())))
parentdir = os.path.dirname(currentdir)
sys.path.insert(0,parentdir)
```

to test_stock.py works. Now I thought Python is easy. What a nightmare ...

Answer (score 0):

> My approach is to avoid writing scripts that have to import from the
>   parent directory. In cases where this must happen, the preferred
>   workaround is to modify sys.path.

but there are other hacking way to it look at this link : [Sibling package imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323860/sibling-package-imports)