# Relative imports in python with local ang global libraries

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

My apps are organized like this:

```
apps/
    code/
        libglobal/
            funglobal.py
    tests/
        project/
            liblocal/
                funlocal.py
            main.py
```

In *main.py* I have:

```
import liblocal.funlocal
```

In *funlocal.py* I try to import *funglobal.py* with:

```
from ....code.libglobal import funglobal
```

When I run

```
python3 -B tests/project/main.py
```

I get an error:

```
from ....code.libglobal import funglobal
ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

I have read a lot of information about relative imports with *python3* and still don't find how to solve this error without changing the *apps* organization radically. Any solution?

Comment: You may want to read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50193944/1388292)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the script being executed has its `__name__` set as `__main__` and defines itself to be on the top level of the package, it refuses to recognize scripts in sibling directories.

You can fix this with a `sys.path` hack:

```
import sys, os
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../..'))
```

or an interseting alternative with setuptools is presented in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50193944/1388292).

Answer (score 0):

Have you a `__init__.py` script in each folder ?

If no, you should create an empty script named `__init__.py` in each folder.