# Trouble importing in sibling directory

Tags: python, import

EDIT: Found a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323860/sibling-package-imports/50193944#50193944)

I'm writing a new package (in jupyter lab) with following structure (folder names start with capital letter):

```
Package
    setup.py
    Rsp
    __init__.py
        Auxi
            __init__.py
            madn.py
            wtuk.py
        LocSc
            __init__.py
            tuk.py
            Examples
                __init__.py
                script.py
```

All **init**.py files are empty.

My current working directory is Examples.

I want to run script.py

In script.py I import  tuk.py by

```
import sys
sys.path.append('..')
import tuk
```

tuk.py imports madn and wtuk. This is where I am having problems.

```
from ..Auxi.madn import madn
from ..Auxi.wtuk import wtuk
```

yields: attempted relative import with no known parent package

```
import sys
sys.path.append('..')

from madn import madn
from wtuk import wtuk
```

yields: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'madn

```
import sys
sys.path.append('..')

from Auxi.madn import madn
from Auxi.wtuk import wtuk
```

yields: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Auxi'

```
import sys
sys.path.append('../Auxi/')

from Auxi.madn import madn
```

yields: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Auxi'

```
import sys
sys.path.append('.../Auxi/')

from AuxiliaryFunctions.madn import madn
```

still cannot find Auxi.

I tried it beforehand with a flat structure (all scripts in the same directory) and it worked.

Comment: Try adding a `print` for `__name__` and `__package__` in each of the imported files. Might shed some light on what's going on

Comment: Did you try adding your Package folder in PYTHONPATH?https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH and then importing giving the full path to madn and wtuk