# Relative Import in python with Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, python-import

I have some trouble with imports in python. I don't exactly understand why there is an error.

I am using jupyter notebook from directory notebooks. I need to import function `prepare_data` which is situated in `source/prepare_data.py`

For importing i have tried to use `from ..source.prepare_data import prepare_data`

As here https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html (Paragraph 5.7) and python shows me an error "attempted relative import beyond top-level package".

[packages](https://pasteboard.co/IocnxQs.png)

Comment: Please share your code and also the error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot import from the parent of your current working directory. Easy way to solve this is working from the root path.

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323860/sibling-package-imports) you can find more info.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the path of the script to your system path:

```
sys.path.append('../source/')
from prepare_data import prepare_data
```

Note that this is a pretty quick-and-dirty hack. The linked answer from @albeksdurf has some better options if you are thinking of packaging up your code.