# Attempted relative import beyond top-level package Error

Tags: python-3.x

I have a folder xyz which contains two files ab.py and cd.py. Im trying to import cd.py in ab.py file.

Below is the folder structure:

```
/xyz
    ab.py
    cd.py
```

I have to import cd to ab

when i do

```
from . import cd
```

This gives me error as: 
Attempted relative import beyond top-level package

Comment: why do you need `from .` ? Wouldn't `import cd` suffice?

Comment: No. It didnt work

Comment: Which directory are you running python from, and with what command?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly. `xyz` is a directory under your working directory.

In that case try to add the current directory to import path.

```
>>> import sys
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> sys.path.append(Path.cwd())
```

And in `ab.py` use `from xyz import cd`

Additional references

[Sibling package imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323860/sibling-package-imports)

[Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time/14132912#14132912)