# Failure to import names when custom project is installed in virtual environment

Tags: python

## Problem

I have read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50193944/7784797), which provides a way to permanently avoid the `sys.path` hack when importing names between sibling directories. However, I followed the procedures listed in that post but found that I could not import installed package (i.e. `test`).

The following are things I have already done

- Step1: create a project that looks like following. Both `__init__.py` are empty.

```
test
├── __init__.py
├── setup.py
├── subfolder1
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── program1.py
├── subfolder2
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── program2.py
```

```py
# setup.py
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(name="test", version="0.1", packages=find_packages())
```

```py
# program1
def func1():
    print("I am from func1 in subfolder1/func1")
```

```py
# program2
from test.subfolder1 import program1

program1.func1()
```

- Step2. create virtual environment in project root directory (i.e. `test` directory)

  - `conda create -n test --clone base`
  - launch a new terminal and `conda activate test`
  - `pip install -e .`
  - `conda list` and I see the following, which means my `test` project is indeed installed in the virtual environment

```py
...
test                      0.1                       dev_0    <develop>
...
```

- Step3: go to the `subfolder2` and `python program2.py`, but **unexpectedly** it returned

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'test.subfolder1'
```

The issue is I think `test` should be available as long as I am in virtual environment. However, it does not seem to be the case here.

Could some one help me? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an empty `__init__.py` file in `subfolder1` to make it a package.

Edit:

You should change the import in `program2.py`:

```
from subfolder1 import program1
```

Or you can move `setup.py` a level up.

Comment: Thank you for your help! But I tried but the problem persists.

Comment: Thank you so much! This works. But I am so confused with those import syntax (for example, why I need to move `setup.py` a level up). Could you provide a pointer to relevant docs/tutorials so that I could avoid similar mistakes.

Comment: Also, when I launch ipython interactive environment and `import test` in `test` folder. I could not call `test.program1.subfolder1.func1()` and the error `AttributeError: module 'test' has no attribute 'subfolder1'` will be returned.

Comment: The use of ``test`` perturbs things since it is a Python module in standard library. If you change the folder name to ``mypkg`` for instance, you will be able to import ``mypkg.subfolder1``. Note that you need to write ``import mypkg.subfolder1`` and not ``import mypkg`` to use ``mypkg.subfolder1``.

Comment: You need to move ``setup.py`` a level up since ``find_packages()`` finds packages in subfolders. I recommend the following documentation: https://packaging.python.org/