# import python package with setup.py

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to import a python package with `my-module.my-function`

I came upon you could do it without modifying `sys.path` because this will require me to invoking the `sys.path append` logic everytime I import `my-module`

([Sibling package imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323860/sibling-package-imports))

Problem is, that when I'm under git controlled repository, `pip install -e .` results in `-e git+git@git-host:git-repo.git@checksum#egg=my-module&subdirectory=path/to/my-module` .

If I try to pip install the `my-module` with the above line (through freezed requirements.txt), it won't be able to install

> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 128: git clone -q
>   git@{our-git-repo}:our-project.git@0b886902a04891546f39e20293359f994107b631
>   /home/eugenekim/virtualenvs/retention/src/retention Check the logs for
>   full command output.

Full output

> Obtaining retention from
>   git+git@our-git-repo:zibann.git@0b886902a04891546f39e20293359f994107b631#egg=retention&subdirectory=apps/retention
>   (from -r requirements.txt (line 104))   Cloning
>   git@our-git-repo:zibann.git@0b886902a04891546f39e20293359f994107b631
>   to /home/eugenekim/virtualenvs/retention/src/retention   Running
>   command git clone -q
>   git@our-git-repo:zibann.git@0b886902a04891546f39e20293359f994107b631
>   /home/eugenekim/virtualenvs/retention/src/retention   fatal:
>   'zibann.git@0b886902a04891546f39e20293359f994107b631' does not appear
>   to be a git repository   fatal: 리모트 저장소에서 읽을 수 없습니다
>
> 올바른 접근 권한이 있는지, 그리고 저장소가 있는지   확인하십시오. Cleaning up... Removed build
>   tracker '/tmp/pip-req-tracker-xjou49h_' ERROR: Command errored out
>   with exit status 128: git clone -q
>   git@our-git-repo:zibann.git@0b886902a04891546f39e20293359f994107b631
>   /home/eugenekim/virtualenvs/retention/src/retention Check the logs
>   for\  full command output. Exception information: Traceback (most
>   recent call last):   File
>   "/home/eugenekim/virtualenvs/retention/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py",
>   line 153, in _main
>       status = self.run(options, args)   File "/home/eugenekim/virtualenvs/retention/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py",
>   line 382, in run
>       resolver.resolve(requirement_set)   File "/home/eugenekim/virtualenvs/retention/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/legacy_resolve.py",
>   line 201, in resolve
>       self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req)   File "/home/eugenekim/virtualenvs/retention/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/legacy_resolve.py",
>   line 365, in _resolve_one
>       abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)   File "/home/eugenekim/virtualenvs/retention/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/legacy_resolve.py",
>   line 295, in _get_abstract_dist_for
>       req, self.require_hashes, self.use_user_site, self.finder,   File "/home/eugenekim/virtualenvs/retention/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py",
>   line 255, in prepare_editable_requirement
>       req.update_editable(not self._download_should_save)   File "/home/eugenekim/virtualenvs/retention/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py",
>   line 725, in update_editable
>       vcs_backend.obtain(self.source_dir, url=hidden_url)   File "/home/eugenekim/virtualenvs/retention/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/vcs/versioncontrol.py",
>   line 494, in obtain
>       self.fetch_new(dest, url, rev_options)   File "/home/eugenekim/virtualenvs/retention/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/vcs/git.py",
>   line 208, in fetch_new
>       self.run_command(make_command('clone', '-q', url, dest))   File "/home/eugenekim/virtualenvs/retention/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/vcs/versioncontrol.py",
>   line 632, in run_command
>       log_failed_cmd=log_failed_cmd)   File "/home/eugenekim/virtualenvs/retention/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/subprocess.py",
>   line 242, in call_subprocess
>       raise InstallationError(exc_msg) pip._internal.exceptions.InstallationError: Command errored out with
>   exit status 128: git clone -q
>   git@our-git-repo:zibann.git@0b886902a04891546f39e20293359f994107b631
>   /home/eugenekim/virtualenvs/reten\ tion/src/retention Check the logs
>   for full command output.

Comment: What is in the logs?

Comment: I couldn't find the log.. I've looked at directory I ran the command, and the virtualenvs I'm in.. no log..

Comment: Try `pip install -vvv` for verbose output.