# Failed to load application: No module named udpecho

Tags: python, amazon-ec2

I am trying to start a socket connection in amazon AMI server, for that I have some existing code which is in python, I am a newbie to python and unable to start that, As I am trying to start that program using this command, I am facing some issues, please check this

```
from twisted.application import internet, service
from udpecho import Echo

application = service.Application("echo")
echoService = internet.UDPServer(7401, Echo())
echoService.setServiceParent(application)
```

but its showing error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/dist-packages/twisted/application/app.py", line 694, in run
    runApp(config)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/dist-packages/twisted/scripts/twistd.py", line 23, in runApp
    _SomeApplicationRunner(config).run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/dist-packages/twisted/application/app.py", line 411, in run
    self.application = self.createOrGetApplication()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/dist-packages/twisted/application/app.py", line 494, in createOrGetApplication
    application = getApplication(self.config, passphrase)
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/dist-packages/twisted/application/app.py", line 505, in getApplication
    application = service.loadApplication(filename, style, passphrase)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/dist-packages/twisted/application/service.py", line 390, in loadApplication
    application = sob.loadValueFromFile(filename, 'application', passphrase)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/dist-packages/twisted/persisted/sob.py", line 215, in loadValueFromFile
    exec fileObj in d, d
  File "udp_server.tac", line 4, in <module>
    from udpecho import Echo
exceptions.ImportError: No module named udpecho

Failed to load application: No module named udpecho
```

What should I do for this to run?
Any Working solution is appreciable

Comment: @sshashank124, may I know the reason why u changed the tag to bash?

Comment: The question is not relevant to python. Rather it is relevant to how you have setup your environment and PATH

Comment: is there anything to do in PATH regarding twistd, Please let me know

Comment: Thanks to @sshashank124, I have added twistd location to PATH, even after I am seeing this error while starting

Comment: Question updated please check @sshashank124

Comment: Do you have a local module or installed module named udpecho?

Comment: I have two files named udpecho.py and udpecho.pyc in the same directory where I am executing this

Comment: I'm not familiar with the details of your setup, but it seems that your file is being executed from another location, therefore it might be an issue with the python import path. Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323860/sibling-package-imports) might help but it's a complete guess. I'd wait for someone who knows about this to answer