# Python 3 absolute imports name collisions

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, collision, absolute

I am working on a project, structured like this:

```
myproject
│ 
├──__init__.py
├──__main__.py
│ 
├── requests
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── test.py
```

I pip-installed my project as a package into venv I am working in with setuptools(described here. [[Sibling package imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323860/sibling-package-imports][]) See the answer titled "Tired on sys.path hacks?")

In every module of my project I use absolute imports like this:

```
from myproject.requests import test
```

The problem is I also use requests library (https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/). It is also installed in venv.
When importing for example `requesets.exceptions.ConnectionError` from test.py, everything works as intended
But when i try to do the same from `__main__.py`, it imports `myproject.requests` submodule instead.(which I already sucesfuly import like this: `from myproject import requests`
How do I fix it, without renaming requests submodule?

Comment: just change the name of your `requests` to something else.

Comment: There has to be another solution, cannot always dodge name collisions.

Comment: any solution for this ?