# Import modules from sub directories - python

Tags: python, python-import

I would like to import modules from subdirectories in an easy way:

I would like to call all the functions in the app.py

```
.
├── app.py
└── testsubdir
    └── testsubsubdir
        ├── utils.py
testsubdir2
└── testsubsubdir2
    ├── utils2.py
```

To do this I use now:

```
sys.path.append('/home/www/testsubdir/testsubsubdir')
sys.path.append('/home/www/testsubdir2/testsubsubdir2')
from utils import <some_function>
from utils2 import <some_function>
```

1. Is there a way to get /home/www as main path of the python calling script, so I don't need to write it every time. Something like this?
   sys.path.append('$MAINPATH.'/testsubdir2/testsubsubdir2')
2. Is there a way to tell put all the subdirectories from the root of the project /home/www to the sys.path, so they are used to include libs?

Answer (score 0):

You need `__init__.py` files in each directory to help Python recognise that these are packages and directories of modules. You should not be modifying `sys.path` like this. See, for example, the docs for [modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html).

For the "sibling" case, you might be able to use `sys.path.append(path)` (or `sys.path.insert(0, path)`, but it's not a very nice solution.  For better alternatives, I would refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323860/sibling-package-imports/50193944#50193944) monster post.

So for your questions 1, you could (with the ugly hack) do `os.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path[0]))`.