# Python: How to import file from subdirectory of parent of parentdirectory?

Tags: python

How can I import file from subdirectory of parent of parentdirectory? I know that this doesn't make sense so let me explain. I want to import the file test.py into the file example.py.

Here is the directory structure:

```
directory1 
+-- directory2
    +-- test.py
+-- directory3
    +-- directory4
        +-- example.py
```

Comment: simply set full path to the file

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi how can I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import a module given the full path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path)

Comment: You could solve this by creating a `setup.py` and installing your code in editable state with pip. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50193944/3015186

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi I need to do it in a relative way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `__init__.py` file inside each directory, parent directory and  subdirectories

```
parent/
    __init__.py
    package_1/
        __init__.py
    package_2/
        __init__.py
    package_3/
        __init__.py
```

---

```
from parent.package_1 import ....
```

---

If doesn't work, try to configure `PYTHONPATH`, in case of **IDE** like **PyCharm**, there's a flag (checkbox) in run/debug configuration

or you might add module to the default path using `sys.path.insert(...)`

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, module_full_path)
```

---

You could check path, using `print(sys.path)`

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure folder also contains an `__init__.py`, this allows it to be included as a package

Answer (score 0):

You have serveral options:

1. Like the comment said you can use a full path:
   /home/User/directory1/directory2/test.py
   Map that file to a variable and use it. (Watch out with using python built in names like test)
2. use `os.chdir` and change your dir to the root of you directory1 and call directory2/test.py
3. make an **init**.py and use it as a package with the `from [directory] import [module]`

Answer (score 0):

Here you go =^..^=

```
from pathlib import Path
import sys

path = Path(__file__).parents
sys.path.append(str(path[2] / 'directory2'))
import test
```