# Module not found error , after installing the wheel file using pip

Tags: python, pip, python-module, setup.py, python-packaging

I have a folder structure for my python package as follows

```
myproject
├── package
|    ├──api
|    |   ├── __init__.py
|    |   ├── main.py
|    |
|    ├──utils
|        ├── __init__.py
|        ├── helpers.py
|        ├── config.yml
├── MANIFEST.in
├── setup.py
```

Content of setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(name='package', 
version='1.0', 
packages=find_packages(),
include_package_data = True)
```

Content of MANIFEST.in

```
include package/utils/config.yml
```

Content of helpers.py

```
import yaml
def add_():
    return 2+3

def config_data():
    with open('project/utils/config.yml') as f:
         yaml_data = yaml.safe_load(f)
    return yaml_data
```

Now I want to import helpers module in main.py

```
from package.utils import helpers
import yaml

print(helpers.add_())
print(helpers.config_data())
```

When I install this package in editable form as and ran main.py , everything is working fine

```
(base) C:\Users\qaise\myproject> pip install -e .
```

snapshot of output of main.py, i.e. output of add_ , and config_data {'qaiser':'alam'} is content of config.yml

[image]

Now when everything was working fine i tried to create wheel file for this package and install created wheel using pip

```
(base) C:\Users\qaise\myproject> python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel 
(base) C:\Users\qaise\myproject> pip install ./dist/package-1.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

[image]

After this , I opened my jupyter notebook and tried to call the function from the helper module I am getting error no module named package, it seemed like it is a path problem but I am not able to resolve it.

[image]

Comment: do you have a ```__init__.py``` in your package dir?

Comment: It looks like you installed into a virtualenv named `base`. Are you sure that's the same virtualenv that Jupyter is using to run the code?

Comment: @Karl Knechtel , yes same env

Comment: I will add __init__.py file in package . let me check after adding file

Comment: after adding __init__ file getting same error , anyhow if __init__ is required in package directory than this should not work if package is installed in editable way.

Comment: Have you ever found a solution?

Comment: @GiuseppeRomagnuolo I have used this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323860/sibling-package-imports/6466139