# How to import packages in Python

Tags: python, python-3.7

My project space is something like this:

```
Project
   Functions_Folder/
                   __init__.py
                   Folder1/
                          __init__.py
                          Function1.py
                          Function2.py
                          Function3.py
                   Folder2/
                              __init__.py
                              Function4.py
                              Function5.py
                              Function6.py
   Codes_Folder/
                  script1.py
                  script2.py
```

I need to import in `script1.py`some functions of the `Folder1` and `Folder2` but that functions also have to import functions on the same directory, i mean, for example `Function4.py` has to import `Function6.py` and `Function3.py`

Please help.

Comment: From the directory containing the `Project` you can run files using `python -m Project.Codes_Folder.script1` and then in files you can just `from Project.Functions_Folder.Folder1 import functions1`.

Comment: Put your scripts on level higher in the folder structure. Usually the folder of the script that is being run becomes the base for imports.

Comment: Look into relative imports.  I think that's the way you want to go here.

Comment: this solution can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323860/sibling-package-imports

Answer (score 0):

You can use relative import

```
├── test
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── a
│   │   ├── one.py
│   │   └── two.py
│   └── b
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── one.py
└── test.py
```

in which the `one.py` file in module `a` is simply

```
from .two import a_two

def a_one(i):
    return 10*a_two(i)
```

the `two.py` file in module `a` is

```
def a_two(i):
    return 5*i
```

the `one.py` file in module `b` is

```
from ..a.one import a_one

def b_one(i):
    return a_one(i)
```

The lines `from ..a.one import a_one` and `from .two import a_two` use relative import.

The whole module can be tested by running the `test.py` file, which is

```
from test.b.one import b_one

print(b_one(1))
```

As for the problem of importing the module `test` in a script, in macOS and linux, you need to set `PYTHONPATH` in `.bashrc` for the module `test` with

`export PYTHONPATH=the_path_to_module_test:$PYTHONPATH`

Comment: But this doesn't quite answer his question.  What if he's down a level, in a directory that's a peer to test?

Comment: @Steve I don't understand, you mean another module that is peer to module `test`, and `test` has to import methods from that module?

Comment: I did that but i recieve an error: KeyError: 'test'

Comment: @DsWqas It works fine on my computer, since I didn't set `PYTHONPATH` for the module `test`, the script `test.py` and `test` must be in the same folder, otherwise `test.py` won't find `test`.

Comment: yes but on my real project space test,py is not in the same folder.... `othefolder/test.py`

Answer (score 0):

So you want to import some functions from `Folder1` and `Folder2` in `script1.py`.

First create `__init__.py` for the `Project` folder

script1.py

```py
import sys
sys.path.append("..")

from Functions_folder.Folder1 import Function1, Function2
from Functions_folder.Folder2 import Function4, Function5
```

Function4.py

```
import sys
sys.path.append("..")

from Folder2 import Function5, Function6
from Folder1 import Function3
```