# Python: import file from sibling directory, where parent directory has the same name

Tags: python, import, module, package

I want to import an object from a module in a package inside another module of a sibling package. But the parent directory has the same name as one of the packages.

Here is the structure I am struggling with:

```
foo{
  __init__.py
  foo{
    __init__.py
    models.py
  }
  bar{
    __init__.py
    models.py
  }
}
```

Inside of `foo` (not the parent) I want to import an object from `bar.models`.

I tried this:

```
from foo.bar.models import MyObject
```

and

```
from ..bar.models import MyObject
```

None worked, how do you do ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sibling package imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323860/sibling-package-imports)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To import from another sibling directory, it's more efficient to use the `sys` module and the `path`:

```py
import sys
sys.path.append('../bar')
import models
# ...
```