# Sibling package import and mypy "has no attribute" error

Tags: python, package, python-import, mypy

I am trying to import a module from a sibling package in Python; following the instructions in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323860/sibling-package-imports/50193944#50193944).  My problem is that the import works... but `mypy` is saying that it's a bad import. I'm seeking to understand why mypy is reporting an error, and how to fix it.

### Directory structure/Code

This is a module that I have installed successfully with `python -m pip install -e .`. I know it is installed because it is listed when I run `pip freeze`, and the project root is listed in `sys.path` when I print that out.

```
mypackage
├── mypackage 
│   ├── foo 
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── db.py
│   ├── bar 
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── model.py
│   └── py.typed
└── setup.py
```

In db.py:

```
from mypackage.bar import model
```

In model.py:

```
class MyClass:
  # implementation irrelevant
```

### Error Message

When I run mypy (`mypy mypackage` from the project base directory), I get the following error:

```
mypackage/foo/db.py:7: error: Module 'mypackage.bar' has no attribute 'model'
```

What confuses me is that, when I open IDLE, the following imports/runs just fine:

```
>>> from mypackage.bar import model
>>> model.MyClass
<class 'mypackage.bar.model.MyClass'>
```

### My Question

Why is mypy showing an error here when the import actually works?  How can I get mypy to recognize that the import works?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Running mypy with the `--namespace-packages` flag made the check run without error, which pointed me to the actual problem: `./mypackage/mypackage/__init__.py` did not exist, causing `mypy` to not pursue the import correctly. Python was working because in 3.3+, namespace packages are supported, but mypy requires a flag to check for those specifically.

Thus, my overall solution was to add the needed `__init__.py` file.

Comment: `--namespace-packages` should perhaps be the default. After all you're **hopefully** targetting Python 3.3+...