# Is there a built-in Python function to add a custom package to the PYTHONPATH?

Tags: python, built-in, sys, pythonpath

Every time I need to use absolute import, for example:

```
from my_package.my_module import my_function
```

I declare my package to the `$PYTHONPATH` by writing down these code lines into my *__ init __.py* file located a the root of my package directory:

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.insert(0, os.getcwd())
```

But I find this solution totally inexpressive... Is this functionality natively supported by the Python standard library?

Comment: Read about venv (python3) or virtualenv (python2) and how to use virtual environements will certainly help you.

Comment: Thanks, but right now I'm on a legacy code. No virtualenv to help...

Comment: This is not related to how old your code is. Have a look at this answer : [Tired of sys.path hacks?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50193944/4611565). It's a bit long to read but I found it very instructive ...