# ModuleNotFoundError: cannot find my Python package

Tags: python, python-import, python-packaging

I have searched far and wide, and have followed just about everything... I cannot figure out why this keeps happening to my Python package I've created. It's not a simple "install dependency and you're good" as it's my own project I am attempting to create.

Here's my file structure:

```
-jarvis-discord
--jarvis_discord_bot
---__init__.py
---jarvis.py
---config.py
---cogs
----__init__.py
----all the cogs are here
```

The error given:

```
++ PWD
line 3: PWD: command not found
export PYTHONPATH=
PYTHONPATH=
python3 jarvis_discord_bot/jarvis.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/buddy/jarvis-discord/jarvis_discord_bot/jarvis.py", line 40, in <module>
    from jarvis_discord_bot.cogs import (
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jarvis_discord_bot'
```

I've tried creating a `pipenv` as well and have had no luck either. Same error as above. There's something wrong with how I'm setting up my Python environment... granted I'm also a newbie.

The weird thing, to top this all off, is that it runs locally on my own machine just fine. So I am at a complete and utter loss for what to do and could use some help and direction on where to go from here.

Thanks!

Comment: The working directory should be `/buddy/jarvis-discord` in order for it to find `jarvis_discord_bot`

Comment: https://sinoroc.github.io/kb/python/python_imports.html

Comment: How do you call your code? Which command do you run?

Comment: Try `python3 -m jarvis_discord_bot.jarvis` (instead of `python3 jarvis_discord_bot/jarvis.py`).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using relative file paths, you have to use
`from .cogs import (`
because it jarvis.py can't see jarvis_discord_bot from one level below.
The . in front of cogs means that it is one level up.

Comment: I tried doing relative file paths and that didn’t work.

Answer (score -1):

Figured out what was the issue!

In my run file, I had to set `PYTHONPATH` from `PWD` to the actual folder of the project. Good luck to anyone reading this in the future!

Comment: You almost never need to modify `PYTHONPATH`, this is a common misconception. Your issue probably lies in how you call your code you need the `python -m package.module` notation. See: https://sinoroc.github.io/kb/python/python_imports.html

Comment: I would also recommend reading this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50193944