# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'folderB' (project attached) in PyCharm for Windows

Tags: python, pycharm, python-import, importerror, python-packaging

> I have done loads of research. Most solutions are incredibly unnatural
> for this simple line of import code.

.

[This is my example project (very simple):](https://ufile.io/i6batwps)

.

TestImport

|_ folderB

... |_ moduleB   (contains "SomeClass")

|_ folderA

... |_ moduleA   (imports "SomeClass")

.

1. When **SomeClass is imported from moduleB into moduleA**,
   (*moduleA.py*: `from folderB.moduleB import SomeClass`)
   this error is encountered:
   " ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'folderB' "

Run command:  `python folderA\moduleA.py`

2. If moduleA is moved to the root folder, the import works
   ( run command:  python moduleA.py )
3. I had marked folderB as source - same error.
   I marked both folders as source - same error.
   I therefore preferred to upload the project with no marked folders.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sibling package imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323860/sibling-package-imports)

Comment: I have received a promising answer. I will admit it/share it as soon as I'll do all the readthrough and apply one of the solutions.

Comment: In the meantime: NO `python -m` please, as `pytest` might be used further. NO strange hard-coded solution as well, please.

Comment: An answer from JetBrains is in the waiting for now.