# Python relative import: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sib1'

Tags: python

I have a project hierarchy like below, when I run `python src/bot/main` I didn't get error. While if I run `python -m src.bot.main` I got an error. Why?

This is my file hierarchy:

```
MyProject
└── src
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── bot
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── main.py
    │   └── sib1.py
    └── mod
        ├── __init__.py
        └── module1.py
```

This is the content of `main.py`:

```
import sys
    

if __name__ == "__main__":

    # sys.path will print the parent folder.
    print(sys.path, end="\n\n")
    
    # my problem is on this line.
    import sib1
    sib1.test()
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/test/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/test/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/Users/me/Desktop/test_py/src/bot/main.py", line 16, in <module>
    import sib1
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sib1'
```

Some conclusion I've made so far:

> Since the output of `sys.path` in both cases include `/Users/me/Desktop/MyProject`, the reason should not related to scope?

---

The output of `sys.path` of both `python -m src.bot.main` and `python src/bot/main`:

```
(test) ✔ me Desktop/test_py % python -m src.bot.main
['/Users/me/Desktop/test_py', '/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/test/lib/python39.zip', '/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/test/lib/python3.9', '/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/test/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/test/lib/python3.9/site-packages']
```

Comment: You'll also probably want to pick a more informative package name than `src`. Placing you package files under `MyProject/src/MyProject` or just `MyProject/MyProject` would be typical. Just make sure that the directory containing `MyProject` (the package) is on your Python path. You'll then be able to use `import MyProject.bot.sib1` and the like.

Comment: Also, you can rename `main.py` to [`__main__.py`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html) to make a package directly executable. E.g., `python -m MyProject.bot` would execute `MyProject.bot.__main__`.

Comment: Some additional helpful reading on structuring packages: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages and https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/

Comment: First, thanks for your kindly links to testing tools! (I've planned to find&learn some of them after I can understand this project structure topic. I'm building a bot for an messaging mobile app btw) Consider `Just make sure that the directory containing MyProject (the package) is on your Python path.` so when I run `python -m ...` this command does this for me?

Comment: Re: python path: the package you're running via `python -m` needs to be in one of the directories in `sys.path`. Otherwise, Python won't be able to find it. You're current working directory (`~/Desktop/test_py` in your example) is always on your Python path, so if you're in the directory containing `MyProject`, using `python -m MyProject.x.y.z` will work. If you're in any other directory, you'll need to add the package directory to your Python path manually. Many IDEs let you do this in the run configuration settings. Alternatively, you can set the env var `PYTHONPATH`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will try my best to clarify each of my confusions in a Q&A form, and organize @Brain's comments along the way:

---

##### Q1: *when I run `python src/bot/main` I got no error.*

The `sys.path` will include the **current directory** containing the file `main.py`, i.e. the interpreter will see the file `MyProject/src/bot`:

```py
import sib1
```

is logically equivalent to:

```py
import "MyProject/src/bot" + "/sib1.py"
```

Hence, no error.

---

##### Q2: *While if I run `python -m src.bot.main` I got error. Why?*

Now it's time to quote @Brain's valuable (first) comment:

> Using `python -m src.bot.main` tells Python that **`src` is a top-level package**. Everything below src in the directory structure will be considered submodules/subpackages of src. **The proper name for `sib1` under that organization is `src.bot.sib1`**. No top-level module named sib1 exists as far as Python is concerned.

(emphasis by me)

So:

- The `-m` option will define the scope (and thus the top-level package) for the file you're going to run.
- All packages not starting from `src.` will be regarded as *built-in* or *third-party* libraries installed in your virtual environment. Since I didn't install any package called `sib1`, you got the error. (the `sys.path` is intentionally ignored in this case, as we there is no implicitly relative import starting from Python 3.3)
- All your relative imports should not go outside of the top-level package `src` (by prepending too many `.`'s in the `import`).

For example, this will work:

```py
from . import sib1
from ..mod import module1    # The `..` is equivalent to the MyProject/src.

module1.hello()
sib1.test()
```

---

Finally, don't test your package by inserting many `if __name__ == '__main__'`. Do so by professional tools:

> If you only need to run submodules for testing purpose, you could consider using more robust testing tools like doctest (lightweight) or unittest (heavyweight).

This is [a good read](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69102148/5290519) I had put 300 bounty on it years ago, you must find a time to read it.