# Reading a users file within module A from a function within module B in Python

Tags: python, module

I have the following directory:

```
└── myproject
    ├── moduleA
        │   ├── __init__.py
        │   ├── users.py
    ├── moduleB
        │   ├── __init__.py
        │   ├── test_in_B.py
    ├── test.py
```

I can easily run `test.py` whose content is the following:

```
from moduleA import users
print(users.name)
```

However, I cannot run `test_in_B.py` whose content is the same as the above and get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'moduleA'` error.

**Contents for replication:**

`moduleA (__init__.py)`

```
from moduleB import *
```

`moduleB (__init__.py)`

```
from moduleA import *
```

`users`

```
name = 'user1'
```

**Question**

How can I run `test_in_B.py` keeping the same structure?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sibling package imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323860/sibling-package-imports)

Answer (score 0):

You can only import modules located in a direct subdirectory of the directory where the .py file is.

There is a workaround described in see [Importing files from different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder). But I would generally recommend avoiding this code structure to make your code easier to read and maintain.

Comment: What you have written should be posted as a comment not an answer.