# Python ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'classes'

Tags: python, python-3.x, module

This is the structure of my project at the moment.

```
classes/
├─ __init__.py
├─ card.py
├─ find.py
├─ player.py
├─ table.py
.gitignore
main.py
```

My `__init__.py`:

```
from .card import *
from .player import *
from .table import *
```

The problem is when I want to import from example player to table.py,
like this:

```
from classes import Player
from classes import Card, CardType, CardValue, HandValue
```

I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/adrian/Desktop/Programozas/Poker/classes/table.py", line 1, in <module>
    from classes import Player
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'classes'
```

Do you have any idea?

Comment: How are you running `player.py`? Is it imported in some script or are you running it directly? Nothing has tried to `import classes` up to this point or you would have failed earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that this error is occurring in ".../classes/table.py", line 1, as you are trying to import `classes.Player` when both `table.py` and `player.py` are contained in `classes`. To do this in `table.py`, you would use `from .player import Player` just like you did in `__init__.py` (instead of `from classes import Player`).

Anything at the same level or above `classes` can be done using this method, but anything defined inside `classes` cannot call up to `classes`, as anything therein does not even know `classes` exists.

Edit: if you need to be able to run both `main.py` and `table.py`, you could do something like:

```
# in table.py
try:
    from player import Player # this should work when running table.py directly
except:
    from .player import Player # this should work when running main.py (it's a relative import)
```

Comment: More on sibling imports: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323860/sibling-package-imports

Comment: Once I change for example the player's import from " from classes import Player" to "from .player .... " I get this error message:
"
    from .player import Player
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
"

Comment: If you need to run `table.py`, you could structure your import block to use a try/except format (`try: from .player import Player except: from player import Player`)... I added this to the original answer with some more details