# 'Module' object has no attribute 'attr'. after applying a change to a package, even after reloading, and other changes work

Tags: python, module, package, attributes

tl;dr: some changes I've made to a package don't appear, depending on where I call them from

To simplify, this is the minimal core of what happens:
**paths:**
`/project/A/__init__.py /project/A/A.py /project/B/__init__.py /project/B/B.py`

## **old code:**

**A.py:**

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.oldAttr = 2
    def getOldAttr(self):
        return self.oldAttr
```

**B.py:**

```
import A
class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = A.A()
        print("old attr: ", self.a.oldAttr)
        print("old attr: ", self.a.getOldAttr())
```

here everything is fine and dandy, I have access oldAttr anyway I want.
However, I wanted to add newAttr to A but I couldn't access it from b so I made the following changes to see whats wrong:

## **new code:**

A.py:

```
print ('loading A')
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.newAttr = 1
        print('defined new attr', self.newAttr)
        self.oldAttr = 2
    def getNewAttr(self):
        print(dir(self))
        return self.newAttr
    def getOldAttr(self):
        print(dir(self))
        print("new attr: ", self.newAttr)
        return self.oldAttr
```

B.py:

```
import A
import pathlib
import sys
from importlib import reload
path_to_A = str(pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.parent.absolute())+'/A'
if path_to_A not in sys.path:
        sys.path.append(path_to_A)
reload(A)
class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = A.A()
        print(dir(self.a))
        print("old attr: ", self.a.getOldAttr())
        print("new attr: ", self.a.getNewAttr())
        print("new attr: ", self.a.newAttr)
```

The result? the attribute list called from B or from getNewAttr contains getNewAttr but does not contain newAttr so calling self.a.newAttr is an error or self.newAttr in getNewAttr, but it exists in the attribute list in getOldAttr and in **init** of A where it can print it fine.

I am using python 3.10.4
I have ubuntu 22.04

I deleted the cache, restarted the computer, reloaded the imports, checked that it reloads using prints, tested the attribute list in differing locations, and hit wall when I saw it differing so wildly

I tried debugging using pdb, in A newAttr is created, but when I step out, self.a.newAttr no longer exists. (and it does exist again later when in getOldAttr, but again does not exist in getNewAttr)

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sibling package imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323860/sibling-package-imports)

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  I was able to import and use the sibling package, my problem arose when I tried to modify it. some modification took, some did not. those who did not were partial - they took when I tried to use them from inside the class in an a preexisting method but not in a new method or from outside the class

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm just stupid. in another part of the code I load from file what I thought were values, but it overrode the dict of the object, changing back the attributes to the old ones