# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src' when trying to import parent directory file from subdirectory file

Tags: python, import, conda, python-import, python-module

I'm using VS code and Conda. I want to import logger.py or exception.py file from the src directory  to the  data_ingestion.py file which is at subdirectory called components in src directory. This is how directory look like:

```
MLProjects
|
 --src
   |
   -- __init__.py
   -- logger.py
   -- exception.py
|
 --components
   --__init__.py|
   --data_ingestion.py
```

Error message as follows

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/components/data_ingestion.py", line 8, in <module>
    from src.exception import logging
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
```

Current working directory is ....\MLProjects

I tried

```
from src.exception import CustomException
from src.logger import logging
```

and then

```
from ..exception import CustomException
from ..logger import logging
```

also tried with

```
from .exception import CustomException
from .logger import logging
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sibling package imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323860/sibling-package-imports)

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achieve this result. One is to put the following piece of code at the begining of your code:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("..")

from src.exception import CustomException
from src.logger import logging
```

Comment: but its still give the same error

Answer (score 0):

use the code **in the top** like this. you should include the global path before import other functions.

**data_ingestion.py** or **logger.py** or **exception.py**

```
import os
abspath = os.path.abspath(__file__)
filename = os.sep.join(abspath.split(os.sep)[-2:])
abspath = abspath.replace(filename, "")
import sys
sys.path.append(abspath)

from src.exception import CustomException
from src.logger import logging
```

if the py source file is here in **MLProjects** directory.

```
import os
abspath = os.path.abspath(__file__)
filename = abspath.split(os.sep)[-1]
abspath = abspath.replace(filename, "")
import sys
sys.path.append(abspath)

from src.exception import CustomException
from src.logger import logging
```

Comment: it gives the same error "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/components/test.py", line 8, in <module>
    from src.exception import CustomException ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'