# Unable to run the python script via CLI

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the project structure below:

```
project_name/
├── provisioner/
│   └── src/
│       └── common/
│           └── utility/
│               └── provisioner_logger.py
└── scripts/
    └── validate/
        └── validate_provision.py
```

Now, I am trying to run this `validate_provision.py`  via `CLI` which causes the error. It has import statements from the common package as listed below:

```
from common.utility.provisioner_logger import get_provisioner_logger
```

I am trying to run this script locally and on the gitlab stage in a docker image. So, I tried running this below command (assuming the current working directory is `scripts`):

```
python ./validate/validate_provision.py "$(cat ../payload.json)"
```

It gives below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./validate/validate_provision.py", line 4, in <module>
    from common.utility.provisioner_logger import get_provisioner_logger
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'common'
```

However, when run via IDE directly this script works fine, with absolutely no errors.

I tried printing `sys.path` from the root to check if my project is listed under the Python paths but in the docker image it is not listed, it is present in my local but still doesn't work from the local as well.

So to include it in my paths, I tried running the below command as well:

`python -m scripts.validate.validate_provision.py`

from the root but the same error. So, what am I missing here? Any help is appreciated.

**P.S**: I have `__init__.py` file in every package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python interpreter needs the fully qualified name of the package or module being imported. You can update the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable to specify the absolute path to the module being imported, so that the interpreter will know to start searching from that path to resolve the import. Something like this:

```bash
PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/path/to/project_name/provisioner/src" python validate/validate_provision.py
```

You will need to determine the absolute path above. So replace the `/path/to` part with the absolute path in your docker container.

Comment: Why is it such a behavior? Since everything is a Python package can't we directly run everything? Because if I run this script directly via IDE it works fine.

Comment: Also, I tried moving the script inside another package of `src` and still the same behavior. @sjking

Comment: Python uses the paths in `sys.path` to resolve imports. Python adds the paths from `PYTHONPATH` to `sys.path` when the program starts. When you run Python on a module, like `main.py`, Python automatically adds the directory of it to `sys.path`. That way, any packages or modules that are children of the `main.py` module directory could be resolved by imports. Any packages that are not children cannot (unless those directories are added to `sys.path`). When you put two packages under `src`, they are siblings, not children. That is why the imports don't work. What IDE are you using?

Comment: I am using IntelliJ. Also, when I moved the script inside `provisioner> src > new_package > .py` and tried running still it failed. Now the hierarchy is also the same.

Comment: Yea, then `new_package` and `common` would be siblings then, so you'd need to update your `sys.path`.

Comment: Yeah, it worked. Thanks a lot @sjking. Now, it gives a different error(again which was never raised when executed directly via IDE). I will look into that but yeah I just hope the Python community will make Python interpreters smarter.

Comment: I am glad I could help! I checked PyCharm (by IntelliJ) and it seems to automatically add some paths to `PYTHONPATH` when you create a run configuration. In particular the "source roots" and "content roots" are added. You might want to read this question about sibling imports too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323860/sibling-package-imports

Comment: Actually, even if it works via IDE, it should be able to run via CLI without any extra configuration. That is something I was actually hoping for. But no worries, thanks for sharing. I will read it for sure :)

Answer (score 0):

If you try to run the script via `python ./validate/validate_provision.py "$(cat ../payload.json)"` it means you are in script dir. Now from there, you are trying to import
`from common.utility.provisioner_logger import get_provisioner_logger`.

This path is not correct in terms of `validate_provision.py`.
It should be something like `from provisioner.src.common.utility.provisioner_logger import get_provisioner_logger` *assuming your project root is at project name.*

If your project doesn't have a parent or root, you need to define one by doing something like:

```py
import sys
import os

# Add the path to 'common' to sys.path
current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
common_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(current_dir, '..', 'provisioner', 'src', 'common'))
sys.path.append(common_dir)
```

Comment: I even tried that as well. But it didn't work too. `from provisioner.src.common.utility.provisioner_logger import get_provisioner_logger
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'provisioner'
`

Comment: can you try `from ..provisioner.src.common.utility.provisioner_logger import get_provisioner_logger` this relative path.

You can also go with `sys` and `path` to add your required dir.

Comment: It gives this error `from ..provisioner.src.common.utility.provisioner_logger import get_provisioner_logger
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package` how can I use sys and path though?

Comment: So you need to build parent/root path for your project. You can try something like:


```python

import sys
import os

# Add the path to 'common' to sys.path
current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
common_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(current_dir, '..', 'provisioner', 'src', 'common'))
sys.path.append(common_dir)

```

*Please modify it according to your project structure.*

Comment: formatting is being messed up in the comment, I have modified my original answer with how to achieve the expected with sys and path. After doing so you can import it as you were trying to do.

Comment: Np @Ranjeet . Just one question, current_dir is the scripts one or the root one?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255427/discussion-between-ranjeet-singh-and-rushhour).