# Building a Python Library - are fully qualified import statements required?

Tags: python

## Python Project Structure

This is what my Python project structure looks like.

- As far as I am aware, this choice of structure is a standard project structure.
- It is possible that I am wrong.
- This choice of structure might have something to do with my question, which is about having to use fully qualified names within the library itself.
- If this design is bad in some way please let me know.

```
my_project/
  bin/
    main.py
  src/
    liburl/
      __init__.py
      url_builder.py
      url_parameter_types/
        __init__.py
        parameter_base.py
        parameter_boolean.py
  pyproject.toml
  .venv
```

---

##### `pyproject.toml`

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project]
name = "my_project"
version = "1.0.0"
description = "My Project"

[tools.setuptools.packages.find]
where = ["src"]
```

---

- I am trying to build a python library which I will use from `main.py`. The library is named `liburl`.
- Within the library code, I appear to require fully qualified import statements.
- Is this expected? It seems odd that I can't use relative imports.

Here is an example:

##### `url_parameter.py`

```
"""
    `url_parameter_types` is a subdirectory in the same directory
    as this file
"""

from url_parameter_types import UrlParameterTristate # this does not work

### ... rest of code
```

Here is another example:

##### `parameter_boolean.py`

```
"""
    `parameter_base.py` is a file in the same directory as this
    file
"""

from paramter_base import UrlParameterBase # does not work

### ... rest of code
```

---

In order to make the example import statements shown above work, I have to use fully qualified imports. That means to do this:

```
from liburl.url_parameter_types.parameter_boolean import UrlParameterBoolean
```

This strikes me as odd for two reasons:

- It is a lot of excess typing
- The thing being imported exists in the same directory as the code doing the importing, I would have thought it was "visible" from other source files in the same directory
- If the directory structure changes (quite a common thing to do when building a library) all the absolute import statements will need to be changed. (For example if a subfolder is renamed or moved - you can probably imagine why this would be a problem without an explicit explanation.)

---

For a final, bonus example, consider the following:

##### `__init__.py`

```
from url_builder import UrlBuilder
```

- I cannot import from the file `url_builder.py` from the root level of this library.
- Instead I have to do this:

```
from liburl.url_builder import UrlBuilder
```

Is this just how Python works? It surprises me that I can't use relative imports.

Comment: For the library which is self contained, relative imports should work.

Comment: FYI an easy way to generate the project structure is by using [hatch](https://hatch.pypa.io/latest/).

If you don't already do, try to execute "> python3 -m my_project"
This solved a lot of import issues for me.

Comment: It looks like you may be trying to create a new canonical question for questions about relative imports in Python. I'd recommended participating in some of the meta discussions on Python import canonicals before trying to do so. I understand you're trying to be helpful, but keep in mind that we already have _a lot_ of content on this topic, and having information spread across more questions makes it more difficult for users to find what they need.

Comment: @Brian61354270 It was a genuine question which I didn't find an obvious answer to here already. (Although I was quite sure it **must** have been asked before.) I figured out the answer from elsewhere, and reposted this as a summary.

Comment: to shorten the import file length you can always import more used functions and classes to the `__init__` of that folder which can shorten it. But not sure of the relative imports

Comment: From the perspective of `parameter_boolean.py`, `parameter_base` is not a top-level module found in any directory on `sys.path`. That means you either use a fully qualified module name that *does* start with a package that can be found via `sys.path`, or a relative path that can start with whatever package `parameter_base` belongs to in resolving the relative path.

Answer (score -1):

The solution is relatively simple. The `.` character can be used at the start of an import statement to indicate that the import is relative rather than absolute, the `.` implying "from current directory" or "relative to current directory".

Similarly `..` can be used for "the directory one level up in the filesystem hierachy" - both of these have the usual meaning which Linux users will be familiar with.

To solve some of the examples posed in the question:

```
from .url_builder import UrlBuilder
```

and

```
from .parameter_base import UrlParameterBase
```

Comment: Word of warning: relative imports aren't relative to the current directory, their relative to the current _package_, and will only work if you're in a package context. They cannot be used to arbitrarily navigate directories. The structure of a package also isn't always in a 1:1 correspondence with a filesystem. The module that actually gets imported by a relative import could be located anywhere in the filesystem, depending on how the package is set up.

Comment: @Brian61354270 Ok - I did not know that. Are there any clear references which explain this?

Comment: There's some good questions on this site that you can find by [searching for questions tagged `python-import` and sort by votes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-import?tab=Votes). [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14132912/11082165) is one of the better ones. The [official import system documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html) is also very readable and contains everything you could want to know.

Comment: Some other good questions: [Sibling package imports](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6323860/11082165) and [Relative imports in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69102148/11082165)